# How to use vendor library in cakephp 3

Tags: phpmailer

I am trying to import vendor library in  cakephp 3 , but am not success yet to do this.

It is giving the error:

> Call to undefined method Cake\Core\App::import()

and this is the code which am using:

```
App::import('vendor', 'PHPMailer', array('file' => 'PHPMailer' . DS . 'PHPMailerAutoload.php'));
```

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: Hi, I have find my answer, the method App::import can not be use in cakephp 3. you have to use require once for this. Thanks.